# Yii2 How to perform where AND or OR condition grouping?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

I am new to Yii-2 framework. How can i achieve following query in Yii-2 framework using activeQuery and models.

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u WHERE u.user_id IN(1,5,8) AND (u.status = 1 OR u.verified = 1) OR (u.social_account = 1 AND u.enable_social = 1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can try this:

```php
//SELECT * FROM users AS u WHERE u.user_id IN(1,5,8) AND (u.status = 1 OR u.verified = 1) OR (u.social_account = 1 AND u.enable_social = 1)
$model = arname()->find()
       ->andWhere(['user_id'=>[1,5,8]])
       ->andWhere(['or',
           ['status'=>1],
           ['verified'=>1]
       ])
       ->orWhere(['and',
           ['social_account'=>1],
           ['enable_social'=>1]
       ])
       ->all();
```

Comment: How to use it with `findOne()`?

Comment: @Faisal `->one()` instead of `->all()`.

Comment: How abut AND (x LIKE 'A%' OR x LIKE 'B%')

Answer (score 36):

try this -

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from('users u')
            ->where(['and',['u.user_id'=>[1,5,8]],['or','u.status=1','u.verified=1']])
            ->orWhere(['u.social_account'=>1,'u.enable_social'=>1]);
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    print_r ($command->sql);die;
```

[more info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html)

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have already knew about database configuration in Yii 2.0, which is basically the same as in Yii 1.0 version.

If you want to use activeQuery, you need to define a ‘USERS’ class first:

```
<?php
    namespace app\models;
    use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

    class USERS extends ActiveRecord {
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'users';
        }
    }
?>
```

Then when you use it，you can write it as following:

```
<?
    $usr_data = USERS::find()->  
            ->where("user_id IN(1,5,8) AND (status = 1 OR verified = 1) OR (social_account = 1 AND enable_social = 1)")
            ->all();    
?>
```

In my opinion, active query provides you a way to separate sql by sub-blocks. But it does not make any sense to apply it when you have such a complicated 'AND OR' WHERE condition..

Answer (score 4):

```
User::find()
    ->select('u_id , u_unique_id, u_first_name, u_last_name, u_username, u_email, u_image,u_phone') 
    ->andWhere("u_status != 2  AND u_id != 1 and u_role in (6,7)")
    ->andWhere(
        ['or',
            ['like', 'u_first_name', $searchVal],
            ['like', 'u_last_name', $searchVal],
            ['like', 'u_username', $searchVal],
            ['like', 'u_email', $searchVal]

        ]
        )
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 3):

U can also do it this way:

```
$data = model::find()
->andWhere('plz = :plz',[':plz' => 40])
->andWhere('plz = :plz',[':plz' => 40000])
->all();
```

Comment: Equal to `$data = model::find()->andWhere(['plz' => 40])->andWhere(['plz' => 40000])->all();`

Answer (score 2):

With `MongoDB`:

```
            $query->andWhere(['and',
                ['$eq', 'status', 1],
                ['$in', 'activity', [1, 2]],
            ]);
            $query->orWhere(['$in', 'yourField', $yourArray]);
```

Tested. Similar with DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Use **OR** condition at first. For example:

```
(new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['id', 'client', 'ts', 'action'])
            ->from('log_client as log')
            ->orWhere(['action' => 'lock'])
            ->orWhere(['action' => 'rel'])
            ->andWhere(['in', 'client', $IDs])
            ->orderBy(['ts' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();
```

It'll be like a "**AND**...(..**OR**..)"

Answer (score 0):

`where()` function of `ActiveQuery` also accepts string as its first parameter that will be used in `WHERE` condition of the query. So easiest way would be to put those conditions in `where()`function.

Assuming you are using `ActiveRecord` model, you can do something like following in your model.

```
$this->find()
       ->where("user_id IN(1,5,8) AND (status = 1 OR verified = 1) OR (social_account = 1 AND enable_social = 1)")
       ->all();
```

Of course you should use prepared statements instead of hardcoding values inside query, but above code is just to give you an idea.

You can find more detail in documentation [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where) and [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail)