# Yii2 using where AND and OR grouping with looping

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, where-clause

I have a keyword "example query" and
I like to query like this

> SELECT * FROM project WHERE `(FLAG=1 and STATUS=1)` and `(NAMA_PROJECT
>   like '%example query%' or DESCRIPTION_PROJECT like '%example query%'
>   or NAMA_PROJECT like '%example%' or NAMA_PROJECT like '%query%')` ORDER
>   BY WAKTU_POST;

I already try this but it give me the query I didn't want.

```
$query=Project::find()->where(['FLAG'=>1,'STATUS'=>1])
->andFilterWhere(['like','NAMA_PROJECT',$q])
->andFilterWhere(['like','DESCRIPTION_PROJECT',$q]);
$words=\yii\helpers\BaseStringHelper::explode($q,$delimiter=' ');
foreach($words as $word){
    $query->orWhere(['like','NAMA_PROJECT',$word]);
}
```

Is it possible to have a loop inside where condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$words = \yii\helpers\BaseStringHelper::explode($q,$delimiter=' ');

$condition[] = 'OR';
$condition[] = ['like','NAMA_PROJECT',$q];
$condition[] = ['like','DESCRIPTION_PROJECT',$q];
foreach($words as $word){
    $condition[] = ['like','NAMA_PROJECT',$word];
}

$query = Project::find()
    ->where(['FLAG' => 1, 'STATUS' => 1])
    ->andWhere($condition)
    ->orderBy(['WAKTU_POST' => SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```

Comment: This is the query that I want. But it give me this error if I don't delete '->all()' `The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses`. Do you know why?

Comment: @GenkaiG using this query in searchModel or dataProvider?

Comment: it for dataProvider

Comment: @GenkaiG Then `all()` not required there. Data Provider require query not query result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Like this

```
Project::find()
        ->where("(FLAG=1 and STATUS=1) AND 
     ((NAMA_PROJECT like '%example query%' OR DESCRIPTION_PROJECT like '%example query%' OR NAMA_PROJECT like '%example%' or NAMA_PROJECT like '%query%')")
->all();
```

[For Detail Information check this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557302/yii2-how-to-perform-where-and-or-or-condition-grouping)

Comment: that works but not I really want. I want to dynamically add OR condition as much the words from the keyword

Comment: then try to use loop for that and concat OR and AND .