# Yii2 Shorten where () and orWhere ()

Tags: yii2

References from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557302/yii2-how-to-perform-where-and-or-or-condition-grouping) is there another way to Shorten where() and orWhere() ?

**Example the code like :**

```
$HrEmployeeShift_opt = ArrayHelper::map(
    HrEmployeeShift::find()->where(['Status' => 'Pasif'])
        ->orWhere(['Status' => 'Rolling'])
        ->asArray()->all(), 'Id', 'Shift'
);
```

**[UPDATE] SOLVED**

Comparing same column for two values or more for the best solution in my opinion is to use `IN Condition` where we can clearly see the detailed code or you can also use `OR` or directly build it like `->where(['Status' => ['Pasif', 'Rolling']])`

Code with `IN` :

```
$HrEmployeeShift_opt = ArrayHelper::map(
    HrEmployeeShift::find()->where(
        [
            'IN',
            'Status',['Pasif', 'Rolling']
        ]
    )
    ->asArray()->all(), 'Id', 'Shift'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are comparing same column for two values. I guess `IN Condition` will also wok.

```
HrEmployeeShift::find()
    ->where(['Status' => ['Pasif', 'Rolling']])
   ->asArray()
   ->all();
```

**OR**

```
HrEmployeeShift::find()
    ->where(['IN', 'Status', ['Pasif', 'Rolling']])
   ->asArray()
   ->all();
```

This will result in a condition `Status IN ('Pasif', 'Rolling')`.

Answer (score 1):

Posted from my mobile you are looking to do it the following way

```
$HrEmployeeShift_opt = ArrayHelper::map(
    HrEmployeeShift::find()->where(
        [
            'OR',
            ['Status' => 'Pasif'],
            ['Status' => 'Rolling'],
        ]
    )->asArray()->all(),
    'Id',
    'Shift'
);
```